# How do you log in to a local account on a domain joined Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: localhost

We had a need to start joining some of our Ubuntu vms to AD.  I default to login to the local domain.
When I have an issue with getting on the machine I have a need to use the local admin account.
How do you indicate that it is a local user.
Thanks for any help that anybody can provide.

Comment: Your domain users should have different names than local users. Then when you login to the local user it should be automatically recognized as such.

Comment: I defaulted the logins to the domain.  I want to login with a local account, which is named localadmin.  In windows, it I do .\username to login using a local account.